# cannot establish a connection with oracle sql developer on Mac M1

Tags: docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running the oracle database 23c- free  in a docker container and able to establish a connection using sqlplus but when Im trying to connect with oracle sql developer using the same username and password, it is giving me the error

**Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=/A7DrgGeT9OZhzllEITTTA==)**

using hostname : localhost
port : 1521

as in sqlplus but it is not getting connected. I would appreciate if someone could assist me with this because I have already spent hours trying different solutions online but to no avail.

Comment: make sure you're getting to port 1521 ON the Linux container... docker run -d -p 1521:1521 ...